# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la imagen de fondo cambie al ingresar desde un celular?

Tags: css

Tengo una imagen predeterminada en un sitio web, pero me gustaría que ésta cambie cuando ingreso desde un celular. Es esto posible hacerlo con ccs?

```
 <div id="page-header-image"></div>

div#page-header-image {
background-image: url(https://www.viajejet.com/wp-content/viajes/Lago-Moraine- 
Parque-Nacional-Banff-Alberta-Canada-1440x810.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Agrega mas detalle por favor, como te gustaria que cambie la imagen? Agrega el codigo donde muestras la imagen y si se puede tambien sus estilos actuales

Comment: Es una **imagen de fondo** o etiqueta **<img>***?

Comment: div#page-header-image {
    background-image: url(https://www.viajejet.com/wp-content/viajes/Lago-Moraine-Parque-Nacional-Banff-Alberta-Canada-1440x810.jpg);
}

Answer (score 0):

Con **CSS** utiliza **mediaqueries**,

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   #page-header-image {
    background-image: url('background4movil.jpg');
 }
}
```

Agregas esta meta dentro del **head**.

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
```

En este ejemplo después de identificar si es dispositivo móvil con **jQuery** cambias la imagen fondo del elemento.

```
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
       console.log('Esto es un dispositivo móvil');
$('#page-header-image').css('background-image','background4movil.jpg');
    }
```